# How do you SELECT two rows having the lowest value that belong to the same group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently using the following query to select two "workers" that could reach a destination by going the slowest speed, taking into account that they all depart when they're able and need to get there at a designated time.

```
SELECT worker_id, department, [ complicated equation using location, destination, departure and arrival time] AS mph
FROM workers
HAVING mph < 500
ORDER BY mph
LIMIT 2
```

This works fine for getting the absolute best two. But what I need to do now, is make sure the chosen workers are from the same `department`. So say John and Sal are from `department` A and Tim and Rita are from `department` B. John's `mph` is 20 and Sal's is 60. Tim's `mph` is 35 and Rita's is 50. Since Tim and Rita's top `mph` is lower (50), they should be selected.

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned that if a department only has one worker that can make it going under 500 mph, the SELECT should return users from a department with two. If there are no departments with two, then choose the best with only one.

Comment: Let's pretend that the complicated equation is just a stored value in the table. With that in mind,consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Turn your second paragraph into a table rather than explain it.  Visual is a lot easier to understand over words.  Much easier to recognize information when you don't have extra words distracting from the end result.

Comment: @Strawberry - Ok, sure. I can in a little while. I'm tied up atm.

Comment: @Cody360c - Aite brother. I'll do it later.

Answer (score 2):

Select worker with top `mph` and filter your query by that department:

```
SELECT w.worker_id, w.department, [ complicated equation using location, destination, departure and arrival time] AS mph
FROM workers w
CROSS JOIN (

    SELECT department, [ complicated equation using location, destination, departure and arrival time] AS mph1
    FROM workers
    HAVING mph1 < 500
    ORDER BY mph1
    LIMIT 1

) w2
WHERE w.department = w2.department
HAVING mph < 500
ORDER BY mph
LIMIT 2
```

**UPDATE**

If you do not want select only one worker, join second worker also :

```
SELECT w.worker_id, w.department, [ complicated equation using location, destination, departure and arrival time] AS mph
FROM workers w
CROSS JOIN (

    SELECT department, 
        [ complicated equation using location, destination, departure and arrival time (by workers) ] AS mph1,
        [ complicated equation using location, destination, departure and arrival time (by w3) ] AS mph3
    FROM workers
    JOIN workers w3 ON w3.worker_id <> workers.worker_id
        AND w3.department = workers.department
    HAVING mph1 < 500 
        AND mph3 < 500
    ORDER BY mph1
    LIMIT 1

) w2
WHERE w.department = w2.department
HAVING mph < 500
ORDER BY mph
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks, but now I see a dilemma. If a department only has one worker < 500 mph, then it would be better to select from a department that has two. I should have thought about that in the OP. Sorry, I'll update it now.

Comment: Cool, I'll try this out and let you know. When you wrote (by w3), I assume you just mean insert "w3." in front of all the necessary parts in the equation, correct?

Comment: I suppose yes, but I dont know this equation

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work brother, but it's not allowing me to use the w3 prefix inside the HAVING clause. Do I need to wrap that section inside it's own SELECT statement?

Comment: You can try to list these columns in `SELECT` and use aliases in `HAVING`. May you show this equation?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. This is the equation: `(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(($latitude - ABS(w.last_seen_lat)) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS($latitude * pi() / 180) * COS(abs(w.last_seen_lat) * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN(($longitude - w.last_seen_long) *  PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) / ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - w.last_seen_time) / 3600)` (the PHP variables are replaced with destination coords)